# Entity Framework 5 DataBase requests

Tags: entity-framework-5

I understand why the first for loop produces one request to the database but why does the second for loop produce 5 requests to the database?

```
class Program
{


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        TAXIDBEntities1 ctx = new TAXIDBEntities1();
        List<TestObject> Tests;

        //This block makes 1 requests to database

      Tests = ctx.TestObjects.ToList();
      for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
      {
          foreach (TestObject item in Tests)
          {
              System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(item.id);
          }
          System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
      }

        //This block makes 5 requests to database

      var x = ctx.TestObjects;
      for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
      {
          foreach (TestObject item in x)
          {
              System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(item.id);
          }
          System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);

      }





    }





}
```

I don't understand what is going on in the second for loop. Could someone explain why the database has 5 requests as shown in Sql profiler?

Comment: Could you post the myEntity and myObject class definitions? I am guessing that myEntity could be a class inheriting from DbContext which implements a method myObject() that returns an object of type myObject, but without seeing the code it is hard to tell what myObject is and what myEntity does.

Comment: I have put the code in now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ToList call in your first example instructs EF to read all of the objects from the database and convert them into an in-memory List.
You then iterate over this list.

In the second loop you are querying the database 5 times.
Each time a foreach loop call GetEnumerator on the DbSet it will query the database.
Entity Framework has no way of knowing that there hasn't been made any changes to the database since last execution of GetEnumerator, and hence it needs to make 5 database reads.